# in Ax=b where x0 and x1 are solutions prove x0-x1 is a solution to the homogeneous system of equations Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

In $Ax=b$ where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are solutions prove $x_0-x_1$ is a solution to the homogeneous system of equations $Ax=0$
It seems like a very obvious proof i just have trouble wording it

Answer (score 1):

$A(x_0-x_1)=Ax_0-Ax_1=b-b=0$.

You need to verify the second equality.

The third equality holds as $x_0$ and $x_1$ are solutions of $Ax=b$